# Qt and exporting vector images

Tags: qt, vector-graphics

I am using QPainter to draw some graphs on the screen and save these graphs as a raster images.

Is it possible to use the same logic I used for rasterizing these graphs to have them exported to vector images that I can use in a PDF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`QSvgGenerator`](http://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qsvggenerator.html) as a "backend" to your `QPainter`, and you'll get an SVG document out of it. (The documentation has an example for how to do that.)

I don't know if you can use that directly in PDFs, but there are converters out there if you need a different vector graphics format.

Comment: Thanks Mat, this is exactly what I was looking for. Actually incorporating the generated SVG in a PDF is a minor feature, but it would be nice i possible! thanks again =)